# Ionicons with React Native results in "Error: Font failed to load"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons, ionicons

I have a React Native iOS app (no Expo) that uses Ionicons. I am loading Ionicons in multiple files with the two lines `import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'` and `Ionicons.loadFont()`.

Last month (September 2022), these two lines loaded Ionicons successfully.

However, after cloning my repo and running `npx react-native run-ios` I receive multiple error messages in my terminal stating `WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6): Error: Font failed to load`. Please can anyone help resolve this?

**Things I have tried that did not work:** 1) deleting node modules and npm install, 2) cd ios && pod install, 3) quitting and rerunning simulator and terminal commands

Answer (score 0):

```
import Ionicons from '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

can you try to import like this and copy paste the terminal result to here

Comment: I get the exact same error